# pass in ruby condition as a parameter

Tags: ruby, sinatra, parameter-passing, datamapper

I need pass one condition with a field "`nombre`" as a parameter

Currently I do:

```
@xcondicion= {:nombre.like => "%#{params[:qyBusqueda]}%"}
clientes= Cliente.all ( @xcondicion )
```

While this works I need something like :

```
@xcondicion= { session[:field_selec].like => "%#{params[:qyBusqueda]}%"} 
clientes= Cliente.all ( @xcondicion )
```

It is feasible to do something like this work?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps make:

`session[:field_selec].like`
`session[:field_selec].to_sym.like`